# Error in CompImageHDU FITS file reading from pyfits

Tags: python, astropy, fits, pyfits

I am getting this error trying to read data from a FITS file. I can see that the file contains the correct data because DS9 viewer shows the image I would expect. The error I'm getting is below. Can anyone help me? Thanks so much.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGDOf.png)

I tried several different methods of accessing hdu[1].data, but all of them end up with this error. hdu[1].compressed_data shows the array I would expect without an error. If I try and run the plot I'm creating with compressed_data, it does not work correctly.

Comment: It looks like a bug in astropy, probably related to using a newer numpy version than supported though off the top of my head I don't remember, but I know there were some changes to numpy that would refuse to coerce data types automatically. That's my guess anyways.

Comment: It also looks like someone finally implemented some code to decompress compressed data by tile which was a Todo item for a long time, but that might have some bugs in it